# Derivation of Marchand Balun equations

Tags: rf, transmission-line, microwave, balun

Could anyone advise about [derivation of Marchand Balun Equations](https://sci-hub.tw/10.1109/tmtt.2011.2164618) ?

Note: Screenshot below is taken from paper :

*New Design Formulas for Impedance-Transforming 3-dB Marchand Baluns*

[image]

Comment: [Analysis and design of impedance-transforming planar Marchand baluns](http://sci-hub.tw/https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/903108) talks about the derivation process, but it is still not complete.

We still need to derive equation (1) of the paper.

Comment: [Microwave Engineering by David Pozar](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=53B65FB687D04417AA2D723DA607B411) has some details on deriving the [coupling coefficient equation](https://i.imgur.com/K8t4XzZ.png).